# Select where not in subquery Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, select, subquery, where-clause

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM servTable, serialTable
WHERE servTable.[Service Tag]=serialTable.[Serial Number];
```

This query, assuming I haven't made any mistakes, should pull all of the information from both tables where the serial and service columns match.

I also need to pull all information from each table where there isn't a match.  I've tried doing that with the following queries, but they don't seem to work.

```
SELECT *
FROM serialTable WHERE serialTable.[Serial Number] <> ( SELECT *
FROM servTable, serialTable
WHERE servTable.[Service Tag]=serialTable.[Serial Number] );
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM servTable WHERE servTable.[Service Tag] <> ( SELECT *
FROM servTable, serialTable
WHERE servTable.[Service Tag]=serialTable.[Serial Number] );
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to learn about SQL joins.

Comment: I tried using joins, but both left and right joins failed to give me the results I wanted.  I tried a left union right and that also failed.  Access doesn't allow for natural joins, which I think is closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: The accepted answers finally do make use of joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Match

```
SELECT *
FROM servTable
INNER JOIN serialTable
ON servTable.[Service Tag]=serialTable.[Serial Number];
```

2 No Match, one side only

```
SELECT *
FROM servTable
LEFT JOIN serialTable
ON servTable.[Service Tag]=serialTable.[Serial Number]
WHERE serialTable.[Serial Number] Is Null
```

There are Find Matched and Find Unmatched query wizards in MS Access.

Comment: I hate that I had to look this up it worked. 

If Access just used NOT IN( code ) Everything would be way better.